# PHP echo in API url

Tags: php, api

I have thist problem with Discogs API.

In this code:

```
echo $stats->get('songtitle');
 
 
$ch = curl_init('https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
$headers = array();
```

I need do something to first line:

```
echo $stats->get('songtitle');
```

Works before ?q=

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtF7S.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think echo is what you want. It seems that you want to assign the value to a variable, and append that to the URL for curl call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do,

You're trying to concatenate you 2 strings like this :

`$ch = curl_init('https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=' . $stats->get('songtitle'));`

Comment: Something like that. $stats->get('songtitle') should show,  eg. Camomilla - Queen Of The Night
So i need echo this, or print, or whatewer works...

Comment: If  you use the code I gave you, if will add the result of `$stats->get('songtitle')` at the end of your url. I think it's what you wanted to do.